# How do I add a comment in GitHub action YML file?

Tags: github, github-actions

In the below syntax:

```
jobs:
  testing:
    name: some test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, xyz ]
    steps:
      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: 1.15.0
        id: go

      - name: Configure git client
        run: git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

---

How do I add `run git client to fix some issue` as a comment for the run command?

Answer (score 12):

#### tl; dr

- Use `: #`

```
- run: git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/" # run git client to fix some issue
+ run: |
+   : # run git client to fix some issue
+   git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

#### ts; dr

I've been searching the official GitHub docs and googling around but couldn't find any working sample.

And I came up with the answer by using the `:` operand which just returns `true` followed by the comment `#` like so:

```yaml
jobs:
  testing:
    name: some test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, xyz ]
    steps:
      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: 1.15.0
        id: go

      - name: Configure git client
        run: |
          : # run git client to fix some issue
          git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hashtag before "run git client to fix some issue" and it turns into a comment.

(YML)

```yaml
jobs:
  testing:
    name: some test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, xyz ]
    steps:
      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: 1.15.0
        id: go

      - name: Configure git client
        run: git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/" # run git client to fix some issue
```

If your not sure what comment prefix a coding language uses, try # or //

Python uses the # prefix for comments and CSharp uses // prefix for comments.

(Python)

```py
# please use my def (actually I thought I made an error in this code but I guess not)

def someDef(string):
    print(string)

someDef("Hi")
```

(CSharp)

```cs
// I have a bad memory and actually can't find any code in my memory to put below
```

If your not sure what I am even going on about, just copy and paste this into your YML file:

```yaml
jobs:
  testing:
    name: some test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, xyz ]
    steps:
      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: 1.15.0
        id: go

      - name: Configure git client
        run: git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/" # run git client to fix some issue
```

Comment: Github actions are written in Python?

Comment: No. I was showing you examples of what coding languages use for comments. Read the full post again

Comment: The .yml file is written in YML so it will use the YML coding language

Comment: @overexchange I have edited the post to add the comment into the correct line. At first I didn't know what you meant by "`run git client to fix some issue` as a comment for the run command" but then I found out you meant to add the comment to the end of the run command.